# mongodb length of a property

Tags: mongodb, size, aggregate

Documents present in my collection,

```
"info"{name : "sample"}, "extraInfo"{ tempCode :"1020200", newCode :"3844"}
```

I want to get all the documents having the newCode length > 3. I have tried below way,`db.collection.find({$where:"this.extraInfo.newCode.length > 3"})`
which returns result as
`{
    "code" : 16722
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `{$exists:true}`  in order to get it right

```
db.collection.find({"newCode" : {$exists:true}, $where:"this.extraInfo.newCode.length > 3"})
```